# Create a new list by summing elements inside the sublists of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list with all partitions of 5:

```
{{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

I want to create a new list that has as sublists the combination of summing two elements of the sublists of the original list, avoiding duplications. So for example, for the lists of partitions of 5, the list I want to create is:

```
{
  {5}, {4+1}, {3+2}, {{3+1, 1}, {3, 1+1}}, {{2+2, 1}, {2, 2+1}}, 
  {{2+1, 1, 1}, {2, 1+1, 1}}, {1+1, 1, 1, 1}
}
```

Which is:

```
{{5}, {5}, {5}, {{4, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{4, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, 
 {2, 1, 1, 1}}
```

I would appreciate it very much if someone could help me to create this.

Comment: You said that you want to avoid duplicates but the result in your example contains duplicates...

Comment: On what condition do you stop summing pairs in the sublists?  Also, what have you tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f, f0, f1, f2]
```

Distinct two-subsets

```
f0[x_] := DeleteDuplicates[Subsets[x, {2}]]
```

Delete elements of `y` *once*:

```
f1[x_, y_] := Fold[DeleteCases[x, y, 1, 1] &, x, y] &;
```

Sum of a two-subset combined with remaining elements:

```
f2[x_] := Join[{Total[#]}, f1[x, #]] & /@ f0[x]
```

If `x` has 1 or 2 elements just take the sum otherwise process using `f2`:

```
f[x_] := If[Length@x <= 2, {Total[x]}, f2[x]]
```

***Examples:***

```
lst = IntegerPartitions[5]
```

> {{5}, {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

```
f @ lst
```

> {{5}, {5}, {5}, {{4, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 1}, {3, 2}}, {{3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1, 1}}}

which matches the desired result except ordering of sub-sublists.

```
lst2 = IntegerPartitions[4]
```

> {{4}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}

```
f @ lst2
```

> {{4}, {4}, {4}, {{3, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}}}